# Trigger event after HTML looped video plays once, while keeping the video looping forever

Tags: jquery, html

I can get an event to trigger with the following code:

HTML:

```
<div style = "z-index:-10">
     <video id ="MoonVid" width="100%"  autoplay="" type="video/mp4" src="vid/Clip 4LowNoSoundHand.mp4"></video>
 </div>
```

JQuery:

```
 $("#MoonVid").bind('ended', function(){
  //console.log("Here we go!")
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#slide-2").offset().top
    }, 3000);
```

});

BUT when I add the loop attribute back into the video tag:

```
<div style = "z-index:-10">
     <video id ="MoonVid" loop= "" width="100%"  autoplay="" type="video/mp4" src="vid/Clip 4LowNoSoundHand.mp4"></video>
 </div>
```

The event doesn't fire, which makes sense since the video is still playing, (or never ending) and thus never calls the event. My question is how to fire the JQuery event after the video plays once, while also keeping the video running indefinitely.

Ideas? And many thanks in advance from this most rad community!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not test it , but it's seems logic to me try it and let me know

Remove the Loop attribute

```
$("#MoonVid").bind('ended', function()
{
    $(this)[0].play();
    $('html, body').animate(
    {
      scrollTop: $("#slide-2").offset().top
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: i always use on :p :p but it's his code , bind will be removed one day :p

Comment: Thanks! Works, like a charm and I switched the bind to .on() (thanks for the heads up!).